# Naturalness and Intuitiveness of marking tense and aspect in the negative but not affirmative

Tags: naturalism, tense-aspect-mood

I'm wondering about the naturalness and intuitiveness of marking tense in negative clauses but not affirmative ones. I'm also wondering *whether a language with this hypothetical feature would be better analyzed in a different way*.

By naturalness I mean how likely it is that a feature like this might evolve somewhere in a real language, and how stable it would be if it did somehow evolve.

By intuitiveness I mean how hard this feature would be to acquire and use correctly in a second language.

The idea is that neither tense nor aspect is marked in the affirmative, but they are marked in the negative.

For instance, let's suppose we have a tense-aspect inventory as follows

```
past          -- covers all past events
recpast       -- covers the recent past, subset of past
rempast       -- covers the distant past, subset of past
present       -- the present
actual        -- covers the past and present
future        -- the future
gnomic        -- covers past present and future, also used for non-temporal denial
instantaneous -- refers explicitly to the topic time
```

Suppose we have a language that uses a negative verb, like Finnish, to negate predicates. Let's make it slightly more general than the Finnish negative verb and have it function as a *negative copula* of sorts as well.

```
book.ACC read.1sg
I am reading the book, I read the book, I will read the book &c

book.ACC read.NPAST.1sg
I did not read the book.

book.ACC read.NRECPAST.1sg
I have not read the book recently.

book.ACC read.NREMPAST.1sg
I didn't read the book a long time ago.

book.ACC read.NFUT.1sg
I won't read the book.

book.ACC read.NPRES.1sg
I'm not reading the book right now.

book.ACC read.NGNOMIC.1sg
I never read the book and never will.

book.ACC read.NACTUAL.1sg
I have not read the book before and am not reading it now.

book.ACC read.NINSTANT.1sg
I did not read the book at the particular time in question.
```

Let's further suppose that nouns can be marked the same way as verbs when they function as predicates.

```
Bob.NOM nobleman.3sg
Bob is a nobleman.

Jane.NOM queen.NPRES.3sg
Jane is not queen right now.
```

The thing that distinguishes this idea from simply having lexemes with meanings like `not yet` is that the choice of the *instanstaneous* negative marker is more marked than and less frequent than the *range* negatives.

Pragmatically speaking, a speaker would be expected to use the *negative morpheme with the broadest scope that is consistent with their knowledge*.

Comment: I don't think this is likely, but I don't have any evidence to back that up.